# When to use おう and when to use おー?

Tags: pronunciation, kana

I have read that both おう and おー are read as "ō".

When to use each one? Is there a rule for it, or is it totally random?

Comment: Could it be that おー　is written in katakana as オー?

Comment: 90 % of the time, you want おう (and こう etc), the rest is おお. おお never happens with an _on_ reading AFAIK.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21272/7810

Comment: Yes, おう in [王様]{おうさま} is read as *ō*, but [追]{お}う, [負]{お}う are read as *ou*... no?

Comment: The one that surprised me a lot when I first ran into it was 炎（ほのお）.

Answer (score 0):

In Hiragana you would use 「おう」 or 「おお」, in Katakana you would use 「オー」.

All of them can be read as "ō".

For example:

フォーク　(fōku)

おおきい　(ōkii)

こうえん （kōen）